Trace of product of positive semi definite matrix and matrix with all negative eigenvalues
Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a Hurwitz matrix, that is, all the eigenvalues of $A$ have strictly negative real parts, and that $S \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix. Then how can prove or provide counter example to the following claim?
$$ 
\mathrm{trace}((A + A^{\top})S) \le 0
$$
My thoughts: I see that $A + A^{\top}$ is symmetric, and that $A^{\top}$ also has eigenvalues with strictly negative real parts. I am not sure how this is useful though.

The statement is not true. There is a kind of converse, however, that is true: if $\operatorname{tr}((A + A^T)S) < 0$ holds for all symmetric positive semidefinite $S$, then $A^T + A$ is negative semidefinite, and it follows that the real parts of the eigenvalues of $A$ are negative.

Note in general that $\operatorname{tr}(MS) \leq 0$ will hold for every symmetric positive semidefinite $S$ if and only if $M + M^T$ is negaitve semidefinite.

This statement is not true. In particular, the fact that $A$ is Hurwitz does not guarantee that $A + A^T$ is negative semidefinite.
As a counterexample, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{-1 & 10\\0 & -1}, \quad S = \pmatrix{1 & 1\\1 & 1}.
$$
$A$ is Hurwitz with eigenvalues $-1,-1$, but
$$
\operatorname{trace}[(A +A^T)S] = 16 > 0.
$$

Could you give some motivation as to how you went about constructing the counter example?

@sixtyTonneAngel Upper triangular matrices are often convenient for these kinds of situations. The entries above the diagonal of $A$ do not contribute to the eigenvalues of $A$, but they contribute (potentially heavily) to the eigenvalues of $A + A^T$ and those of $A^TA$.
